# WUBI installation error- cannot unpack wubi.exe

Tags: installation, wubi

I was trying to download Ubuntu on Windows installer mode. I downloaded the `Wubi.exe` file and when I ran it, it said `cannot unpack c:\users\dell\downloads\Wubi.exe`. What should I do?

Comment: right click on the exe and click `Run as Administrator` if you are on vista/7

Answer (score 3):

Try downloading it again. The file might be corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this happens with media on which the filed from ISO have not been burnt properly. But sometimes it is possible that media that was running properly starts giving you issues after a failed install attempt.

I had a properly working Ubuntu install CD. I tried installing it on boot but then had to power down my laptop because the freaking installer hung. The console showed me a kernel panic and I was never able to use that disc again.

Either way, you have to burn again.